# Specify Scala Spark dataframe schema with string longer than 256

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
var df = ...from source

val leghtMetadata = new MetadataBuilder().putMetadata("maxlength", length).build()

df = df.withColumn(colName, df(colName)as(colName, leghtMetadata))
```

this is my code. but dont apply metadata

Comment: What's the question? What is not working? Any input/output? Any error? Please add more details if you expect some answer.